# Draggabilly.js events in the Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using Draggabilly.js inside a Backbone view as follows:

```
var appView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
     var draggie = new Draggabilly(this.el);
     draggie.on('dragEnd', this.updateModel); //This works by I can access the this.model
    },
    events: {
      'dragEnd':'updateModel' //This doesn't work
    },
    updateModel: function(instance, event, pointer){
      //Here I want to update my model bassed on the pointer's x and y
      //However I can't access this.model
    }
)};
```

Draggabilly provides and event `'dragEnd'` for when the draginng is over. However I can integrate this in my Backbone view as an event.

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access to the `View` context you can do:

```
draggie.on('dragEnd', _.bind( this.updateModel, this ));
```

But, if you want to remove the listener of `dragEnd` later it might be useful to use `bindAll` in your initialize code:

```
initialize: function() {
   _.bindAll(this, 'updateModel');
}
```

Check the Backbone documentation for further [info](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this).